# 5V DC Voltage stabilizer circuit

Tags: voltage-regulator, adc, boost

I need a circuit or preferable a ic that have a stable output of 5VDC. Input range may vary between 4 - 5.5V.

I want to "drive" a Vref on a ADC. The operating voltage for this ADC can be 2.7 - 5.5V, so no proplem here. But I would really like a stable external Vref, and I have seen a variation between 4.2 to 4.9V on the system.

Any ideas. 
I was looking to TPS61175 or TPS40304, but there have to be something simpler?
ADCs to be used: MAX11614 or MCP3208
Kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you say your supply voltage ranges from 4.9V - 4.2V, I'd think about choosing e.g. a 4.096V reference instead (or 2.048V reference as as Photon points out your supply swings a bit too close to 4.096V for many references), and divide the input voltage accordingly. Otherwise you will have to boost the input voltage and then use this to supply the reference *and* ADC.

Boosting the supply is certainly possible but adds complexity, since you don't really want to drive an ADC directly from a switching regulator, so having either some pretty decent filtering or an LDO before the analogue section would be necessary.
If you do want to look at this option there are plenty of simple little boost converters which would be worth looking at (e.g. something like an [MCP1640](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1669480.pdf) set to 5.5V followed by a 5V LDO such as a [TPS76350](http://uk.farnell.com/texas-instruments/tps76350dbvt/v-reg-ldo-0-15a-5-0v-smd-76350/dp/8461384RL) with *typical* 180mV dropout - you would have to do some reading to work out worst case scenarios and see if things work for your specs - maybe a 6V switcher would be better for headroom but I just picked the first one I found which was max 5.5V) although I think this option is less preferable to simply manipulating the input voltage instead)

If you want an accurate and stable reference, then generally you would use a precision voltage reference IC with an opamp buffer to drive the reference input with a low impedance. Some reference ICs can drive the input directly.

Usually the ADC datasheet will have an example or two of different options for driving the ref input (some ADCs may have an internal reference you can use as an alternative also)

Precision references commonly come with voltages that are a power of two mV-wise, like 1.024mV, 2.048mV, 4.096mV, etc. This makes it easy as e.g. for a 10 bit converter and a 1.024 reference, you have 1mV per LSB.

For your two parts, the Maxim has an internal reference option of 4.096V, but the Microchip part needs an external reference. In the datasheet an example circuit is given using a reference IC:

[image: ADC ref example]

This uses one of their 4.096V ICs, but if you need 5V, you can simply swap it for a 5V reference - check on one of the major vendors and do a parametric search for "5V reference". Here is an [example using Farnell](http://uk.farnell.com/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=203961%20110033312&Ns=P_PRICE_FARNELL_UK%7C0&locale=en_UK&appliedparametrics=true&getResults=true&suppressRedirect=true&isRedirect=&originalQueryURL=/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=203961&No=0&getResults=true&appliedparametrics=true&locale=en_UK&divisionLocale=en_UK&catalogId=&skipManufacturer=false&skipParametricAttributeId=&prevNValues=203961) (~150 results)

The other option is to use the reference with a buffer opamp for lower impedance, which may be necessary in some circumstances, here is an example:

[image: ADC reference with opamp buffer]

The above came from this [TI app note](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa118/sboa118.pdf).

Whatever you choose, make sure you decouple the reference input (and the ADC supplies also of course) well and pay attention to PCB layout (e.g. analogue and digital sections)

Comment: As a note, MCP1541 apparently needs 4.3 V minimum Vdd, so it won't quite work with OP's stated input voltage (and especially won't work with the contradictory requirement of 4 - 5.5 V input).

Comment: @Photon - thanks for pointing that out, I forgot the input dropped so low. The 2.048V with an input divider would work okay (or altering supply specs to raise the low point of the swing) It might be useful to know a little more about the circuit in order to be clear on the finer points.

Comment: Yes, I read that also (MCP1541). Thanks for excellent answer!

Answer (score 2):

One of the converters you suggested (TPS61175) is a *boost* converter. The other is a *buck* converter. A boost converter creates a high voltage from a lower voltage input. A buck converter creates a low voltage from a higher voltage input.

Since your system has an input voltage range that can be either above or below the output that you want, neither of these will work.

There is a type of SMPS circuit called a *buck-boost* converter that may be able to do what you are asking.

That said, the output of a SMPS always has some ripple voltage, and it is not a good choice to use for the reference voltage of an ADC. That ripple will be seen as noise in the ADC reading. If you go this way , you are very unlikely to get the benefit of the 12-bit precision of the ADCs you mentioned.

My suggestion is to use a boost converter to generate a highish voltage, say 8 V. Then filter the output as well as you can afford, and use a *precision reference* circuit to generate the ADC reference. A precision reference is a lot like a linear voltage regulator, but it trades off high accuracy for limited current supply capability (100 uA - 10 mA max current are typical numbers). However, this should be no problem --- the MAX11614, for example, only needs 40 uA in to its REF input.

As Rawbrawb mentions, it's also advisable for best performance to use a linear regulator for the main power supply of the ADC.

Answer (score 1):

As you seem to be aware, you need to regulate at close to the available voltages.  So a regular or even a LDO regulator will be problematic.  You need too much input head room to be able to use a linear solution.  So a SMPS type solution that linked to is appropriate.  However, it's not advisable to connect a switcher into a sensitive part like a ADC esp. the Vref part of it.  So I'd boost it up higher than needed and then use a linear to supply power for BOTH the ref and the ADC.