# How create a low-voltage boost (~4v to 5v)

Tags: dc, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, boost, battery-operated

I am looking for a circuit that will go from a Li battery that has a voltage between 3.6v and 4.3v up to 5v - and I have seen similar questions such as [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/94518/powering-5v-device-with-usb-and-or-battery) and [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/51944/5v-dc-voltage-stabilizer-circuit), but those just recommend alternatives instead of providing a solution to what seems like a common problem.

More information: I am looking to keep a Raspberry Pi alive, which needs a stable 5v (not less!) at 1A minimum in order to keep it fully functional (yes it can run at 3.3v, however it loses Ethernet functionality, which makes it not useful for my purposes anymore)

Comment: Why is the buck-boost solution suggested in the links you provided not a viable option?

Comment: Why not just use a buck-boost converter? I would also recommend running at a slight overvoltage if 5v is the minimum stable voltage, as even a regulator may temporarily dip below if the load changes drastically.

Comment: @DanLaks because "ONLY Battery presented, USB absented. Bq24032a's OUT pin voltage will equal to battery's voltage approximately...of course...( with no load)." does not meet the 5v minimum

@-JarrodChristman - it's pretty stable up until 4.9V or so, would you have a sample buck-boost converter schematic around these voltages to recommend?

Comment: But if you lose power, wouldn't whatever is not battery backedup stop working and Ethernet be useless?

Comment: @GustavoLitovsky - the other stuff is backed up by off-the-shelf battery backups that provide 120VAC, only positioning one of those where this is located would be overkill - POE would be a potential solution, but probably more expensive and less efficient than this

Comment: Your quote refers to the BQ24032A only. The TPS61032 boost convertor (when connected to the output of the BQ24032A) will deliver a solid 5V whether online or offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are any number of commercial boost regulator ICs that will meet your needs. Note that the peak switch current for a boost converter is greater than the load current, so you will want one that is rated for > 1A. VOUT/VINMIN*1.2 is a good start. Anything greater than 2A would probably work for you. Check out the LT3436 or LT3580, to give just two examples.